# talking to an OLE Automation (IDispatch) server from PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, ole-automation

I'm interested in communicating with an OLE Automation (IDispatch) server from Windows Powershell.  Can anyone point me to some simple sample code that illustrates doing this?  I know I can use New-Object -com My.App.Interface to create the object, but then talking to it is a different matter.  In this case its an OLE Automation (IDispatch) interface, so I'm not just calling methods right on the returned object, I'm calling the Invoke method of IDispatch.

So, anyway, just wondering if anyone can point me to some samples for doing this that I can use as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a=new-object -com ....
[System.__ComObject].invokemember(<Method>,[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::invokeMethod,$null,$a,<args>)
[System.__ComObject].invokemember(<Property>,[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty,$null,$a,<args>)
```

Comment: This is a great start -- I found code similar to this when google'ing it initially.  But not sure how the <args> will work out for the variety of types you encounter in an OLE Automation interface.  Is there a powershell wrapper for VARARG?  That's why I was hoping to find some samples of someone actually interfacing with an OLE Automation object from powershell to see how they dealt with the args (in and out) and all.

Comment: Not having any luck trying to use InvokeMember as shown on an OLE Automation server.  Anyone have an example of this being used correctly?

Comment: Never figured this out -- there's a unique issue with a COM interface which accepts out params -- looks like this just isn't something you can invoke directly from PowerShell.